# Trimming off non numerical stuff and store them in an array using replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex, string, trim

Supoose I have input a line "MOVE R1, R2",  I split the words with respect to white space and store them     individually into an array token[] as follows:

```
String[] token = new String[0];// array initialization
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("a.txt");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));         
//Read file line by line and storing data in the form of tokens
While((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
token = strLine.split(" ");// split w.r.t spaces                
}
```

So the elements at each index are as follows:
    token[0]=MOVE
    token[1]=R1,
    token[2]=R2

But what I want is as follows:
    token[0]=MOVE
    token[1]=1
    token[2]=2

I want to store only the numerical values in the token[i] where i>0, trimming off R and comma(,). 
I m unable to figure out how to use relaceAll() with arrays. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll be wanting to use regex I imagine, you might want to add it as a tag and alter your question appropriately to attract attention from guys with regex knowhow.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

This will trim off the non-numeric stuff.

Comment: or other way, alternatively: String digits = text.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");

Comment: how can implement it in my code. I m unable to figure out how to use relaceAll() with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Replace before tokenizing:

```
while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
strLine = strLine.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
token = strLine.split(" ");// split w.r.t spaces                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s=s.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

for your individual split string elements in the while loop..